# Amazon Redshift - Joining table and finding out unmatched rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have two tables whose pseudo structure would be something as follows:

**User_master**

```
user   pfid
------------
reno    2
andrew  3
reno    4
rosh    5
rosh    8
john    7
```

**HR_master**

```
user    pfid
-------------
andrew   3
reno     4
rosh     9
john     12
```

**Roaster_master**

```
user    pfid
--------------
andrew   3
reno     4
rosh     10
john     12
```

I need to join all 3 tables on column *user* and find the rows in HR_master where pfid doesn't match with **any** equivalent entry in User_master. If you note one of the entry for "reno" matches, while none of the entry for "rosh" matches.

It would have been an easy tasks if there were only one entry in **User_master**,the complication arise because of multiple rows.

The expected output is

```
USM.user   USM.pfid   HRM.pfid   RM.pfid
-----------------------------------------
  rosh       5|8        9           10
  john        7         12          12
```

As asked, here is the query that I have compiled:

```
select
  UM.email,UM.pfid as UMpfid,
  HRM.pfid, RM.pfid
from user_master UM
left join HR_master HRM on (HRM.email=UM.email)
left join Roaster_master RM on (RM.email=UM.email)
where UM.pfid != HRM.pfid
```

The above query returns "reno" as well, whereas it should not come as one of the row in User_master  has pfid matching.

Comment: The question is well defined above, but please also add your current sql and results. (for what you have tried so far)

Comment: @JonScott I have added my current sql